# Meaning of the five fields of the ANSWER SECTION in dig query

Tags: dns, dig

Here is the ANSWER SECTION when I run `dig www.google.com`:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.         108     IN      A       74.125.239.115
www.google.com.         108     IN      A       74.125.239.114
www.google.com.         108     IN      A       74.125.239.116
www.google.com.         108     IN      A       74.125.239.113
www.google.com.         108     IN      A       74.125.239.112
```

I think the first field contains the URL and the second field contains the port number. I am not sure about the third and fourth fields. I think the fifth field contains the IP address.

I've reviewed http://www.madboa.com/geek/dig/ and https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/909/Understanding+the+dig+command, and am still unsure what each section represents.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Reference: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch15/#answer and http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/a.html

The first field is the **NAME**: The domain name being returned

The second field (108 in your example) is the **TTL** in seconds.

IN is the **CLASS**. Here, IN stands for Internet.

A is the **TYPE**. Here, A stands for mapping a domain name to an IPv4 address.

The last field is of course the **IP Address**.